# How do I convert Midi Messages to a Midi File Python

Tags: python, midi

I have a List containing Lists in python with midi data.

```
[64.0, [128, 62, 127, 0]]
```

It is

```
[Time, [MidiStatus,data1,data2,data3]]
```

How do I convert this to a MIDI file?

EDIT:
I have tried MIDO but when I save it will note store the note properly.

EDIT2:
I have found a solution using all mido rather then pygame

Comment: Have you looked into the available python midi modules?  This has certainly been done before.   There are some complexities involved in storing time in a midi file, etc.

Comment: Could you show an example of your code with Mido that doesn't store the note properly?